# Insert data from uploaded Excel document to database using ASP.net (Vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, file-upload

Im working on a web application, I want to Know if there is a possibility to insert the data fields information of an Excel file into my SqlServer database after uploading it, using Asp.net(VB.net) ??

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in VB.NET:

```
Protected Sub btnExport(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim TheFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(MapPath(".") & "\" & "filename.xls")

    ' Connection String to Excel Workbook 2010 (xlsx)
    ' Dim excelConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~\directory\filename.xlsx") + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"""

    ' Connection String to Excel Workbook 2003 (xls)
    Dim excelConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~\directory\filename.xls") + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""

    ' Create Connection to Excel Workbook
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [sheetname$] ", connection)

        connection.Open()

        ' Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
        Using dr As DbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

            ' SQL Server Connection String
            Const sqlConnectionString As String = "Data Source=server; Initial Catalog=database; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password"

            ' Bulk Copy to SQL Server
            Using bulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString)
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "SqlServerTableName"
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Additional tip: try to set IIS to run 32-bit applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Here is the bird's view of possible basic steps:

1. After uploading - save Excel file under temporary unique name
2. Open OLEDB connection to the uploaded file
3. Read it (either via OleDbDataReader - if it's a huge file, so you don't have to load it into  memory at once, or into DataTable if it's small)
4. Run your queries, Stored procedures to update SqlServer DB with acquired data
5. Delete uploaded file

Comment: It's a pretty common code, you can find many examples online. For example Google "Path.GetRandomFileName" or "VB.NET read Excel file OLEDB" or "DataTable TVP"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void export(string excelfilepath)
{

    string ssqltable = "tdatamigrationtable";

    string myexceldataquery = "select student,rollno,course from [sheet1$]";
    try
    {
        //create our connection strings
        string sexcelconnectionstring = @"provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + excelfilepath +
        ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 8.0;hdr=yes;\"";
        string ssqlconnectionstring = "server=mydatabaseservername;user
        id=dbuserid;password=dbuserpassword;database=databasename;connection reset=false";

        //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table
        oledbconnection oledbconn = new oledbconnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
        oledbcommand oledbcmd = new oledbcommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
        oledbconn.open();
            oledbdatareader dr = oledbcmd.executereader();
            sqlbulkcopy bulkcopy = new sqlbulkcopy(ssqlconnectionstring);
            bulkcopy.destinationtablename = ssqltable;
            while (dr.read())
            {
                bulkcopy.writetoserver(dr);
            }

            oledbconn.close();
        }
        catch (exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Data.Common
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fname As String
        Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
            If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                fname = ofd.FileName

            End If
        End Using

        Dim olecon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ;Data Source=" & fname & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;"""

        Dim dBaseConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(olecon)

        dBaseConnection.Open()


        SSQL = "select  [LOT],[IMAGE],[STYLENO],[VENDOR] from [Sheet1$]"

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SSQL, dBaseConnection)

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

        Dim ds As New DataSet

        da.Fill(ds)


        Using dr As DbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If SHCONNECTION.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                Call SHconn(MCONNECTIONSTRING)
            End If

            Using bulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(MCONNECTIONSTRING)
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DBimage"
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ds)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```